# Script to restart another script

Tags: bash

Hello I am trying to write a script to restart other script from command line.
usage should be:

restart someotherscript.sh

cat restart

```
#!/bin/bash

for pids in $(ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
do 
kill -9 $pids
done
echo test
sleep 10
$1 &
```

output is:

```
 root@xxxx:/scripts# restart pricealert.sh 
 Killed
 root@xxxx:
```

My restart script is killing itself.
What is wrong here? Can you please help me?

Comment: Better use `pgrep` or even `pkill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is finding itself in the search results because the command you used to start the script contains the script name you're trying to kill.

You can add an if statement to fix this (`$$` is the pid of the running script):

```
if [ "$$" != "$pids" ]; then
     kill -9 $pids
fi
```